# TxTextControl License issue in TFS Build

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, txtextcontrol

Here are the steps I followed to build the application on VSTS and
deploy on the integration branch.

Since the build was failing in VSTS due license which is not installed
on the build machine we followed the steps mentioned in this [link](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/blog/archive/20161128/).

1. We have referred the following assemblies from the custom folder ex 
       C:\CustomFolder\bin
       TXTextControl.Server.dll
       TXTextControl.dll
       TXDocumentServer.dll
2. We have the following entry in the licenses.licx

   ```
   TXTextControl.ServerTextControl, TXTextControl.Server
   ```
3. Here is the  command I ran to create the licenses resource

   ```
   D:\MyAssembly\bin> LC /target: MyAssembly.Net.dll  /complist:..\licenses.licx  outdir:..\  /i:"D:\MyCustomFolder\bin\TXTextControl.Server.dll"
   ```

> Microsoft (R) .NET License Compiler [Microsoft .Net Framework, Version 4.6.1055.0]
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Processing complist '../licenses.licx'... Creating Licenses file
>   ../\MyAssembly.net.dll.licenses...

But this seems to be not working anything I am doing wrong here…….

Comment: Did you contact TX support?  It's been years since I've dealt with them but they were helpful then.

Comment: I referred to that article and made a test with windows forms application, it builds successfully with Hosted agent. According to your description, it seems that you are using class library, what're detail steps to build project (e.g. add references, Code)

Comment: I contacted theTxControl Team but the solution suggested by the team is not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the License compiler and adding logical name to the resource to remove the namespace which was getting added to the resource.

Here is the fix for the embedded resource.

```
 <EmbeddedResource Include="myassembly.net.dll.licenses">
   <LogicalName>MyAssembly.Net.dll.licenses</LogicalName>
 </EmbeddedResource>
```